# MERN stack express route seems to be ignored (always pending)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an existing app that is properly posting to the server, and now  want to add a login page to it with some new routes. It's set up using the MERN stack, without mongoose. I'm not getting any errors when I try to post, I'm just seeing that the post remains forever in a pending state and no data is actually posted back to the database. Additionally, console.log inside of my route is never logged, so it seems like the route is not being found. Here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');


//Require the .env file for mongoDB connections
require('dotenv').config();

//middelware setup
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
//app.use(connection(app, uri, {}) );

//routes
const plantRouter = require('./routes/plants');
const loginRouter = require('./routes/loginUser');

app.use('/plants',plantRouter);
app.use('/loginUser',loginRouter);




app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
})
```

The second route is the one in question. I've been testing just with the signup route, so login is empty right now.

```
const router = require('express').Router();//our created Router
const db = require('../db-manager');

//request to look up a user for login
router.route('/:id').post((req, res) => { 
    
})

//request to create a new user login
router.route('/addNew').post((req, res) => {
    console.log("hit"); 
    res.send("done");
})
//export the router
module.exports = router;
```

The only unusual thing I can think of is that I have 2 buttons that can be used to "submit" the form, in quotes because neither is actually a submit button. They just post the axios request. I did try swapping to a single submit button setup like I use on my other forms, though, and ran into the same forever pending problem, so that is probably not related.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { LabeledTextInput } from './data-components.component';
import "../cssAssets/controls.css";


export default class UserLogin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super (props);

        this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
        this.attemptSubmit = this.attemptSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = { 
            username: '',
            password: '',
            role: ''
         };
    }


    onChangeValue(value, name) {
       
        this.setState( {
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    attemptSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = { 
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            role: this.state.role
        }

        if (e.target.name == "login")
        {
            console.log("login");
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/loginUser/'+this.props.match.params.id, user)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
        }
        else
        {
            user.role = "User";
            console.log("sign up " + user.password + " " + user.username + " " + user.role);
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/loginUser/addNew', user)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
        }

    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div className="container">
                        <h1>Login</h1><br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <LabeledTextInput
                                onChangeValue={this.onChangeValue}
                                label="Username:"
                                value={this.state.username}
                                name="username"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <LabeledTextInput
                                onChangeValue={this.onChangeValue}
                                label="Password:"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                name="password"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button name="login" onClick={this.attemptSubmit} className="button btn btn-primary"> Login </button>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button name="create" onClick={this.attemptSubmit} className="button btn btn-primary"> Sign Up </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the route might not be found?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as it turns out, is simply that I needed to completely restart the server to make the new routes pick up (I was using nodemon, and didn't realize it doesn't do a full restart).

So, if you think everything is working and the routes are just not being hit, try restarting the server (and maybe all of VSCode) at least once.